# Unable to accept user's license agreement in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Installed Eclipse IDE from the terminal in Ubuntu 12.04 for android app development. I was now asked to download the required files from "Install New Software" in the IDE itself where it asks me to accept the User's Licence Agreement. I click on the radio button which says that I'm accepting the agreement but the finish button doesn't get highlighted and I'm unable to click it!

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works.  Depending on what you're installing, you might have to:

1. Accept multiple license agreements (accept each and click next).
2. Toggle to accept all and accept all the agreements at once.

What @rafal said was right.  In some cases you need to scroll to the bottom of the window.

If none of this solves the problem, add a screenshot to your question so we can "see" your window.

Answer (score 1):

for my case, Eclipse indigo / juno, Ubuntu 12.04, virtual box operating system, any reinstall or update or install other version of eclipse or close/restart do not work, and toot me more than 3 hrs.... (BUT MY WINDOWS 7 HOST ECLIPSE JUNO GOT IT WHEN INSTALLED) :(

The only way I've found and worked was that, and possibly where the bug was:
For example, we want to install the eclipse marketplace.
When you choose Help -> Install new Software -> select the version of your eclipse -> GENERAL PURPOSE TOOLS, DO NOT CLICK NEXT YET, but open the list of "general purpose tools", search the sub element you want, in our case is the "Marketplace", then click Next, follow all the requirements, and when I agreed with the licences, Finish Bottom enabled immediately.

Hopefully this is where exactly the bug is, and hope similar problems can be fixed in this way. Good luck guys!

Answer (score 1):

The same happened for me when I was trying to install a plugin in eclipse. I went to HelpResolution:
In case Marketplace is available in the Help menu, go for Marketplace and search the plugin or software in the search menu of Marketplace. 
You can see the finish button enabled at the end of Accept License page.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably need to *read* the licence agreement before accepting it**.

Seriously.

Some applications check whether you have spent some reasonable time reading it, whether you have scrolled to the end, etc.

Comment: Tried that too. Not working!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with egit plugin. I tried it a few times in a row and after re-doing the entire wizard about the 5th time it worked. I had also exited and restarted Eclipse a few times in between.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting all the items and "I agree" or words to that effect.

Hit the "Finish" button not the "Next" button

Answer (score 0):

I had to leave the accept radio button at do not accept, scroll through the license condition text and THEN toggle the radio button to accept.